# Kafka - Real Time Streaming with Web Service

Tags: web-services, hadoop, webserver, real-time, apache-kafka

I am trying to stream a data through web service and planning to consume it into kafka. Streaming data would be of size 4 MB, at max it can goes upto 10 MB. Data source SDK is written onto .Net and Apache Kafka does not provide DLL for its consumer and producer. Its very typical to write Kafka producer and consumer in .Net and we can't use github Kafka producer.

My Questions are -

1. Is web service is good option for real time streaming?
2. Is web service able to stream upto 10MB of data without impacting the performance of web server and data ingestion?
3. Is there any better approach to solve this issue?

answer with authentic source will really helps me.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think, the used of webservices is a good option to push stream data if you would like to decouple your front-ends either from kafka or an API written into a specific language. But that depends of your use-case.

You should have a look at the open-source Kafka REST Proxy provided by the Confluent Distribution (http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/index.html).

It will allow you to produce/consumer messsage though webservice.

If you expect to push messages with a max size of 10MB don't forget to increase the following kafka properties (as by default kafka is tuned for 1MB messages).

- max.message.bytes
- replica.fetch.max.bytes
- fetch.message.max.bytes (consumer config)